# Qt6, qmake seems to ignore configurations specified in the .pro file

Tags: error-handling, qmake

I am using qt6 in Mac OS Ventura 13.5.

I was looking for the cause of the error message "Project ERROR: failed to parse default search paths from compiler output".

In the .qmake.stash file, I get "QMAKE_MAC_SDK.macosx.SDKVersion = 14.0", and was trying to set SDKVersion to 13, as suggested in some forums.

In doing this, I realized that qmake is ignoring my settings in the .pro file.
For example, in the .pro file I set:
QMAKE_CC = /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/gcc
QMAKE_CXX = /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/g++

while in the .qmake.stash I get:
QMAKE_MAC_SDK.macx-clang.macosx.QMAKE_CC = /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang
QMAKE_MAC_SDK.macx-clang.macosx.QMAKE_CXX = /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang++

I delete the .qmake.stash file every time before $ qmake, but I always get the same result.
So now I am trying to understand why the .pro file is ignored.
Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks everyone,
Frances